# SwiftUI with MVVM + Realm database: How to create a list with elements?

Tags: swiftui, realm

I want to use a realm database in my SwiftUI app and I would like to apply the MVVM pattern. Unfortunately when I create a list with the elements in my database I get a `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value:` error message

**DatabaseManager:**

```
class DatabaseManager{

    private let realm: Realm
    public static let sharedInstance = DatabaseManager()

    private init(){
        realm = try! Realm()
    } 

    func fetchData<T: Object>(type: T.Type) -> Results<T>{
        let results: Results<T> = Realm.objects(type)
        return results
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
class FlashcardDeck: Object, Codable, Identifiable{
    @objc private (set) dynamic var id = NSUUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var title: String?
    var cards = RealmSwift.List<Flashcard>()

    convenience init(title: String?, cards: [Flashcard]){
        self.init()
        self.title = title
        self.cards.append(objectsIn: cards)
    }
    
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class FlashcardDeckViewModel: ObservableObject{
    let realm = DatabaseManager.sharedInstance
    @Published var decks: Results<FlashcardDeck>?

    public func fetchDecks(){
        decks = realm.fetchData(type: FlashcardDeck.self)
    } 
}
```

**View**

```
struct FlashcardDeckView: View {
    private let gridItems = [GridItem(.flexible())]
    @StateObject var viewModel = FlashcardDeckViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView{
                LazyVGrid(columns: gridItems, spacing: 30){
                    ForEach(viewModel.decks!) { item in // <----- ERROR APPEARS HERE
                        FlashcardDeckItem(deck: item)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Flashcard decks")
        }
        .onAppear{
            self.viewModel.fetchDecks()
            print(self.viewModel.cards?[0].title) // <------ prints the title of the deck! So this element exists
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that my database has an element and if I try to print the name of the deck in the `fetchData()`function it will be displayed. I know the line `ForEach(viewModel.decks!)`isn't beautiful code, but this is just for testing/debugging now.

Comment: Try unwrapping `decks` before using it - your error suggests it is nil. `if decks = viewModel.decks { ForEach(decks) {...} }`

Comment: Please handle optionals in case they are nil. This `viewModel.decks!` tells your app that for sure, decks will never be nil. But it *could* be nil `var decks: Results<FlashcardDeck>?. You can provide a default value in case it's nil or even prevent the code from running if it is - that will prevent oddball, hard to track down crashes and make your users happy.

Comment: Is there any option to initialize an empty Results<T>? Otherwise I don't know how I can provide a default for a Results<T> like this: `ForEarch(viewModel.decks ?? ...) { .... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include it conditionally, like

```
    NavigationView{
      if viewModel.decks == nil {
        Text("Loading...")
      } else {
        ScrollView{
            LazyVGrid(columns: gridItems, spacing: 30){
                ForEach(viewModel.decks!) { item in // <----- ERROR APPEARS HERE
                    FlashcardDeckItem(deck: item)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Flashcard decks")
      }
    }
```

Comment: When I try this I get the error message `Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to expected argument type Results<FlashcardDeck>`

Comment: Yes, you right, missed type of your decks, see updated.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it. Is there any "more elegant" way to write this line of code `ForEach(viewModel.decks!)` ?

Comment: Have your viewModel return an empty array when decks is nil.

Comment: Sure, but the problem is that I'm working with Results<T>. Solution like `ForEach(viewModel.decks ?? [])`is not possible